# Is there a way to create a new "thread" for my sql script?

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have done a fair amount of SQL and so I don't think this is possible.  But it seems like it should be.

Say I have a script that looks like this:

```
DECLARE @first INT
SELECT @first = 1
RAISERROR ('First Done: %d', 0, 1, @first) WITH NOWAIT

DECLARE @second INT
SELECT @second = 2
RAISERROR ('Second Done: %d', 0, 1, @second) WITH NOWAIT

DECLARE @third INT
SELECT @third = 3 
RAISERROR ('Third Done: %d' , 0, 1, @third) WITH NOWAIT
```

The result for me is always:

```
First Done: 1
Second Done: 2
Third Done: 3
```

**What I am wondering is if there is a way to tell sql server to run each section in parallel?**

Something like `Parallel.ForEach` (to use a C# method).

So, say if the second part took longer, my results would be:

```
First Done: 1
Third Done: 3
Second Done: 2
```

In my real example, I have many statements (in the same query) that all run independently of each other.  I am hoping that there is a way I can get them running at the same time and reduce overall time for the query to run.

Comment: Short answer is "no, not possible". Longer answer is "kind of" - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8478822/1663001

Comment: Yeah my understanding is SQL Server will decide on its own if it should run something in parallel. However, if your break the tasks into different Jobs it more likely